# How to Get a line of text from html to Python

Tags: python, html

Im creating a program that prints out the Ip adress of the User.
So what im trying to do is to get the Html of ipchicken.com and print out only the "Name Address" Part.
here is my code so far:

```
import urllib              
sock = urllib.urlopen("http://ipchicken.com")
htmlSource = sock.read()           
sock.close()
print htmlSource
```

Now how do i get the ip part of the html printed out?

and if there are other ways to get an ip of the user using python,please include that aswell :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run a regex to find IP structure patterns over `htmlSource`

```
ips = re.findall('(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})',
                 htmlSource)
```

the variable `ips` will contain all literals with a IP structure.

The whole code would look like:

```
import urllib,re           
sock = urllib.urlopen("http://ipchicken.com")
htmlSource = sock.read()           
sock.close()
print htmlSource
ips = re.findall('(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})', htmlSource)
print "IPs in page", ips
```

Comment: Screen scraping... and that too with regexps. I don't really recommend it.

Comment: Thanks! That was huge help! plus i learned something new xD. Thanks!

Comment: It seems trivial to solve this with a regex. Other solution like parsing the all the XML or using BeautifulSoup seems an overkill to me, just a matter of colours ... I guess :)

Comment: Switching to something that gives you programmatic output rather than something meant for human consumption is the "right way" in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. But I don't think that was the question here.

Comment: The question carried some bad smells that needed fixing.

Comment: I agree as well. But evangelizing about best approaches in every question would be quite imposible to sustain in SO. Every question would be endless.

Answer (score 2):

Use a HTML scraping library, like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use something that's more programmatic like [ifconfig.me](http://ifconfig.me) rather than ipchicken which is ad laden. ifconfig.me behaves different when being queried by something like cURL.

If you want to parse the HTML and get out the IP address with ipchicken, use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

*update* : http://ip.appspot.com/ is something that has *only* a programmatic interface.

Comment: Yes, I Used That Link for the code instead of ipchicken now xD thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) to grab a text within another text. If you provide the relevant part of your `htmlSource` we can post one.

Here are some posts on retrieving the IP address: [How to find out your IP address in Python](http://commandline.org.uk/forum/topic/352/)

Comment: "to grab a text within another text.", yes. [It's probably not the right tool for HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), though.